# Printing .triad_census() results in a TypeError

Tags: python, typeerror, igraph

- Python: 3.7.4 x64
- OS: Windows 10 Pro x64, no admin rights
- WHL file from:
  https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#python-igraph

File "total_edges.csv" (71kb): https://uni-duisburg-essen.sciebo.de/s/WLDD4ytkjekVcIL

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import igraph as ig

df_edges = pd.read_csv("data/total_edges.csv")
g = ig.Graph.TupleList(df_edges.itertuples(index=False), directed=True)
tc = g.triad_census()
print(type(tc))
print(str(tc))
```

Error:

```
<class 'igraph.datatypes.TriadCensus'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/XXX/count_triads.py", line 18, in <module>
    print(tc)
  File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\igraph\datatypes.py", line 642, in __str__
    for _ in range(rowcount):
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Correct result should be:

```
003 : 56140031 | 012 :   665018 | 102 :    98255 | 021D:    12355
021U:      344 | 021C:     1759 | 111D:      399 | 111U:     2577
030T:      304 | 030C:        8 | 201 :      323 | 120D:       56
120U:      188 | 120C:       55 | 210 :      179 | 300 :       49
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print(list(tc))
```

shows the correct numbers.